# Formatting date time in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Has anyone tried out formatting datetime, which is specified by its data set, in SSRS?

```
=Format(Fields!Date.Value,"dsDateTime","dd/MM/yyyy     hh:mm:ss")
```

This expression is not working.

Comment: But I still need to specify the dataset, otherwise aggregate function specification issue occurs. I have tried  this one also..... =Format(CDate(Fields!Date.Value,"dataset"), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")    but not successful yet.

Comment: input from sql is 01/01/2011 21:01:11 and excepted to get in this format dd/MM/yyy      hh:mm:ss. @curiousguy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way than this two suggested.

> Right click in your expression > Placeholder Properties > Number >
>   Date > Then pick your desired format.

Comment: Very straight forward!

Answer (score 1):

Add the format to the field's format property.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may need to cast to date first.

```
=Format(CDate(Fields!Date.Value), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm.ss")
```